# Calculate difference between two number in a file

Tags: bash

I want to know if it is possible to calculate the difference between two float number contained in a file in two distinct lines in one bash command line.

File content example :

```
Start at 123456.789
...
...
...
End at 123654.987
```

I would like to do an echo of 123654.987-123456.789

Is that possible? What is this magic command line ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  /Start/ { start = $3 }      # 3rd field in line matching "Start"
  /End/ {
    end = $3;                 # 3rd field in line matching "End"
    print end - start         # Print the difference.
  }
' < file
```

If you *really* want to do this on one line:

```
awk '/Start/ { start = $3 } /End/ { end = $3; print end - start }' < file
```

Comment: Why use `< file`  just `awk '{...}' file` is also fine.

Comment: You did it Adam Liss ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with this command:

```
start=`grep 'Start' FILENAME| cut -d ' ' -f 3`; end=`grep 'End' FILENAME | cut -d ' ' -f 3`; echo "$end-$start" | bc
```

You need the 'bc' program for this (for floating point math). You can install it with apt-get install bc, or yum, or rpm, zypper... OS specific :)

Comment: This answer gives a more accurate result! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't support floating point operations. But you can split your numbers to parts and perform integer operations. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(( ${2%.*} - ${1%.*} )).$(( ${2#*.} - ${1#*.} ))
```

Result:

```
./test.sh 123456.789 123654.987 
198.198
```

EDIT:

Correct solution would be using not command line hack, but tool designed or performing fp operations. For example, `bc`:

```
echo 123654.987-123456.789 | bc
```

output:

```
198.198
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a weird way:

```
printf -- "-%s+%s\n" $(grep -oP '(Start|End) at \K[\d.]+' file) | bc
```